# Parsing csv with a date.time column to C#

Tags: csv, datetime, parsing, csvhelper

Hi i'm still a novice at C# and i'm using [Csvhelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

I've tried to read a csv file listed like

```html
SurgicalDeviceId CreatedAt
-1 1/01/2000 0:00
-2 1/01/2000 0:00
1 19/02/2019 12:39
2 19/02/2019 12:39
3 19/02/2019 12:39
```

i've mapped it like so;

```
public class Instrument
    {
        //csv map
        public int SurgicalDeviceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
    public sealed class InstrumentMap : ClassMap<Instrument>
    {
        public InstrumentMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.SurgicalDeviceId);
            Map(m => m.CreatedAt);
        }
    }
```

and my read text is as such;

```
public static List<Instrument> SplitCsv(string csv)
    {
        var textReader = new StringReader(@"D:\CSVStuff\Jasper.csv");

        var csvr = new CsvReader(textReader);

        var instrumentList = csvr.GetRecords<Instrument>().ToList();

        return instrumentList;
    }
```

I've breakpointed below this code and it's debugged so no errors appear but running the code produces no list and i'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your `ClassMap` before getting your records.  You should also put your readers in using statements so that their resources are properly disposed of.

```cs
public static List<Instrument> SplitCsv(string csv)
{
   using(var textReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\CSVStuff\Jasper.csv"))
   using(var csvr = new CsvReader(textReader))
   {
      csvr.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<InstrumentMap>();

      var instrumentList = csvr.GetRecords<Instrument>().ToList();

      return instrumentList;
   }
}
```

Your culture info may properly handle the dates.  On my computer it threw an error, so you might need to add `TypeConverterOption` to your ClassMap.

```cs
public sealed class InstrumentMap : ClassMap<Instrument>
{
    public InstrumentMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SurgicalDeviceId);
        Map(m => m.CreatedAt).TypeConverterOption.Format("d/MM/yyyy H:mm");
    }
}
```